# Entity Design for web service

Tags: entity

My client will be sending the request as described below in SOAP format.

```
<RequestTimestamp>2014-08-22T11:28:00Z</RequestTimestamp>
<SystemID>TestProcessor</SystemID>
<Version>1<Version>
<QWID>201507080000001</QWID>
<QWID>201507080000010</QWID>
<QWID>201507080000001</QWID>
<QWID>201507080000010</QWID>
<QWID>201507080000001</QWID>
<QWID>201507080000010</QWID>
<CHL>201507080000010</CHL>
```

In every request, **QWID** should come as batch and I proposed below entity design to adopt above data.

```
public class APIRequest
```

{

```
[DataMember]
public DateTime RequestTimestamp;

[DataMember]
public string SystemID;

[DataMember]
public int Version;

[DataMember]
public string[] QWID;

[DataMember]
public string CHL;
```

}

With above entity design, SOAP request generated as

```
      <request xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/QWID.Services" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <a:RequestTimestamp>0001-01-01T00:00:00</a:RequestTimestamp>
    <a:SystemID>WireSystem_001</a:SystemID>
    <a:Version>0</a:Version>
    <a:QWID xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">

      <b:string>20141023010232_ORG99000002_CTR.fedwire</b:string>        

      <b:string>20141023010842_ORG99000001_CTR.fedwire</b:string>
    </a:QWID>
  </request>
```

My client expecting the SOAP request in the form of `<QWID>201507080000001</QWID>` instead of coming under `<QWID><b:string>20141023010232_ORG99000002_CTR.fedwire</b:string> </QWID>` as string tag.

How do i do the entity design (without grouping of QWID) to achieve client expectation as described above? Please help me on this?